# iPad Camera Overlay Orientation issue

Tags: ipad, camera, orientation, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller

I am developing an app for iPad2 which allows user to take photos. I am going to use custom overlay for image picker. But this overlay view does not detect the orientation of the device.

I have tried with
`didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` and `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`. But non of them are working. This is how I am creating overlay.

```
@interface CameraOverlayController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>


-(void)setupImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    self.picker.sourceType = sourceType;

    if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {        
        self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;        

        if ([[self.picker.cameraOverlayView subviews] count] == 0)
        {
            CGRect overlayViewFrame = self.picker.cameraOverlayView.frame;

            if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
                NSLog(@"Initially Landscape and height : %f" , CGRectGetHeight(overlayViewFrame));
            }
            if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
                NSLog(@"Initially Portrait and height : %f", CGRectGetHeight(overlayViewFrame));
            }
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, CGRectGetHeight(overlayViewFrame) - self.view.frame.size.height - 10.0, CGRectGetWidth(overlayViewFrame), self.view.frame.size.height + 10.0);

            self.view.frame = newFrame;
            [self.picker.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.view];
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I detect the rotation of the device within camera overlay?

Many thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solove above issue by myself. 
The above function has been recreated like this.

```
-(void)setupImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    self.picker.sourceType = sourceType;
    if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {
        self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;                
    }
}
```

Then I have use navigation controller delegate. Within this function I could capture the device orientation and solved my issues.

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Thanks for viewing this.

Comment: hi can you expound more on this? Can you show me how you implemented willShowViewController? thanks

Comment: This willShowViewController is a navigation controller delegate. Implement all your UI (navigationController toolbar, buttons etc.) inside this method and add to the viewController as a subview. I hope this will help you.